# Javascript asset pipeline: 404 error - How to include Google analytics code in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to include Google Analytics in my Rails app but am having problems with Rails its asset pipeline.

I created a new file (`app/assets/javascripts/google-analytics.js`) in which I included the Javascript code supplied by Google. To `application.html.erb` I added the line: `javascript_include_tag 'google-analytics' if Rails.env.production?`.

Unfortunately it doesn't work in production. After pushing to Heroku, the source code includes: `<script src="/javascripts/google-analytics.js"></script>`. But it can't find the javascript file, i.e., if I click this link in the source code it produces the 404 error page. What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update:** It works if I add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['google-analytics.js']` to `production.rb`. It does now work if I add this line to `assets.rb` instead of `production.rb`. I would prefer to place it in `assets.rb` to keep it uncluttered. Does anyone understand why it isn't working with `assets.rb`?

*Would it be a good alternative to directly include the JS file in the folder `/public/assets/google-analytics.js`? Then I wouldn't need to include the file in `/app/assets/javascripts/google-analytics.js` and I wouldn't need the precompile lines in `production.rb` or `assets.rb`?*

---

Heroku log tail before update:

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-1d520c66bc88***583e462611.css" host=***.herokuapp.com request_id=***  fwd="***" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=93
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-2b1c01f66fb87e***bd707657bc1acf7.js" host=***.herokuapp.com request_id=*** fwd="***" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=93
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/javascripts/google-analytics.js" host=***.herokuapp.com request_id=*** fwd="***" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=1708
app[web.1]: Started GET "/javascripts/google-analytics.js" for *** at 2015-07-15 11:11:23 +0000
app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/google-analytics.js"):
app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
etc.
```

Comment: How does the server redirect the requests to assets? Does it take the asset urls and then looks them up in the asset folder? Do you have some kind of logging available?

Comment: I added the server log to the post. Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails system needs to know pre-compilation of that file.
By default it works with `application.js` but if you create a new manifest file, you have to include it.

In `config/initializers/assets.rb` or `production.rb` add the below line:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << ['google-analytics.js']
```

Comment: I've been reading several posts on the topic but I fail to understand. Javascript's "manifest file" I understand refers to javascript.js? Why is `google-analytics.js` referred to as *manifest* file? And why do I need to tell Rails that it needs to precompile this file? Since it's in the javascripts folder and since `application.html.erb` includes `//= require_tree .`, shouldn't Rails automatically precompile all js files in this folder? For images and stylesheets I also just added them to the images/stylesheets folder, and Rails precompiles them and I can access them without problems.

Comment: Although I don't understand it, I decided to just try it and added the line to `assets.rb`. Unfortunately, it didn't make a difference and still generates a 404 error.

Comment: Have you tried to add:
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << ['google-analytics.js']
in production.rb?

Comment: Thanks Umar, if I place it in production.rb instead of assets.rb then it indeed works! What does this mean? Is there something wrong with my assets.rb? I would definitely prefer to place it in assets.rb instead of production.rb because to me that just makes it more uncluttered/obvious.

Comment: If we place anything in initializers, then they are accessible everywhere in your project.

Comment: Thanks Umar, I don't understand your last comment. If they are "accessible everywhere in your project" if we place it in an initializer, shouldn't that mean that it should work when we place it in assets.rb (since this is an initializer)? How can we make it to work when we place it in assets.rb?

Comment: I posted a follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31456598/5086345)

Answer (score 0):

You have your asset pipeline enabled ?

Then include

```
//= require google-analytics.js
```

in `application.js` file and then run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

on production server and restart your rails application and check.

Comment: I think I do, but how can I check whether I have the asset pipeline enabled? Shouldn't `//= require_tree .` in `application.js` automatically require `google-analytics.js`?

Comment: By default it is enabled.
Ohh if you have require_tree . then you don't need to add it again manually.

You tried precompiling the assets ?

Comment: Yes, when deploying to Heroku, Heroku automatically runs `assets:precompile`.