# Rails asset pipeline: Can it be good practice to include asset in public folder instead of asset folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I've been struggling a bit with adding Google Analytics to my Rails 4 app (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31428864/5086345)).

I've got it working by adding the JavaScript code, that Google supplies, in a new file in `/public/assets/google-analytics.js`. In `application.html.erb` I have included:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'google-analytics' if Rails.env.production? %>
```

This works but I thus haven't included the JavaScript file in `app/assets/javascripts/` and placed it in the public folder instead. The JavaScript file thus isn't compiled.

Would you say that this is good practice / the Rails way?

I choose this solution because otherwise I could only get it to work if I also added `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['google-analytics.js']` to config/environments/production.rb (it didn't work if I added this to the initializer assets.rb). An I find this a bit more cluttering than the above solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case it might be best to just add the analytics script to the head section of views/layouts/application.html.erb

Another option would be to create a view/shared directory with a file called _analytics.hml.erb and paste the analytics  tag in there and do this in your views where you need it:

```
<%= render 'shared/analytics' %>
```

No need to precompile it at all if you just render it in a partial. What is 'best practice' is subject to opinion, but if you render it in a partial you'll ave yourself some time configuring and troubleshooting the way you're trying to do it.

In my opinion, the partial is the more 'Railsy' way, unless you specifically need someone to be able to access www.your-site.com/analytics.js

Comment: Thanks Nick, since I want to use it in all my views, adding the script to the head section of application.html.erb makes sense. But wouldn't that be the same as what I'm doing now (doing it through a link to a file in the public folder keeps application.html.erb a bit more clean)? 
My question is more, is it okay to place files directly in the public/assets folder instead of using the asset pipeline? And if not, why not?

Comment: I'd stick with the partial. Generally speaking, the public assets folder would be used for files you want to make available to anyone. I'd even go so far as to recommend putting the script in app/assets/javascripts if you really don't want to go the route of the partial. You get the same effect with either public/assets or rendering the partial, but the partial is more in line with the 'Rails' way. Spree uses a partial to render the analytics script, if it matters.

Comment: Do you have any reason you would want anyone to be able to access www.yoursite.com/analytics.js? If not, I'd go with the partial.

Comment: Okay, that also gives me a better idea of what the public folder is for and that it's not a good solution here. Why/when would you suggest using a partial instead of app/assets/javascripts/?

Comment: For me it's just a matter of personal preference. I've had trouble with the asset pipeline before and I prefer to avoid precompiling whenever possible.